# Exhaustive match pattern binding

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

In Rust I have an enum `MatchType`

```
enum MatchType {
    Exact,
    Lower,
    Greater,
    Other,
}
```

I use it for my `compare` function to compare two `String`. If `MatchType` is `Exact/Lower/Greater` I want to convert both `String` to `f64` and compare their values (In case `parse` failed I consider comparison result to be `false`).

I can easily achieve it with some boilerplate code like so:

```
fn compare(str_one: String, str_two: String, match_type: MatchType) -> bool {
    match match_type {
        MatchType::Exact => {
            let f_one = str_one.parse::<f64>();
            let f_two = str_two.parse::<f64>();

            if let (Ok(f_one), Ok(f_two)) = (f_one, f_two) {
                f_one == f_two
            } else {
                false
            }
        },
        MatchType::Lower => {
            let f_one = str_one.parse::<f64>();
            let f_two = str_two.parse::<f64>();

            if let (Ok(f_one), Ok(f_two)) = (f_one, f_two) {
                f_one < f_two
            } else {
                false
            }
        },
        MatchType::Greater => {
            let f_one = str_one.parse::<f64>();
            let f_two = str_two.parse::<f64>();

            if let (Ok(f_one), Ok(f_two)) = (f_one, f_two) {
                f_one > f_two
            } else {
                false
            }
        },
        MatchType::Other => false,
    }
}
```

But I wanted to try something more concise: First check if the match is one of those three `Exact/Lower/Greater` then parse strings and then perform the actual comparison like so:

```
fn compare(str_one: String, str_two: String, match_type: MatchType) -> bool {
    match match_type {
        MatchType::Exact | MatchType::Lower | MatchType::Greater => {
            let f_one = str_one.parse::<f64>();
            let f_two = str_two.parse::<f64>();

            if let (Ok(f_one), Ok(f_two)) = (f_one, f_two) {
                match match_type {
                    MatchType::Exact => f_one == f_two,
                    MatchType::Lower => f_one < f_two,
                    MatchType::Greater => f_one > f_two,
                    // --- Non-exhaustive --- 
                    _ => false,
                }
            } else {
                false
            }
        },
        MatchType::Other => false,
    }
}
```

It works, but the inner match is non-exhaustive, of course simple `_ => false` fixes it, but I was wondering if I could somehow tell Rust compiler that the inner pattern is only those 3 enum variants `Lower/Greater/Exact`.

I tried to use *pattern binding* like so:

```
fn compare(str_one: String, str_two: String, match_type: MatchType) -> bool {
    match match_type {
        float_match @ (MatchType::Exact | MatchType::Lower | MatchType::Greater) => {
            let f_one = str_one.parse::<f64>();
            let f_two = str_two.parse::<f64>();

            if let (Ok(f_one), Ok(f_two)) = (f_one, f_two) {
                match float_match {
                    MatchType::Exact => f_one == f_two,
                    MatchType::Lower => f_one < f_two,
                    MatchType::Greater => f_one > f_two,
                    // --- Non-exhaustive error here ---
                }
            } else {
                false
            }
        },
        MatchType::Other => false,
    }
}
```

But I still get `non-exhaustive` error. Any way to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. However, this pattern (matching against part of the values inside another `match`) is fairly common. Usually I see it with a panic (`unreachable!()`) on impossible variants, but returning a default value is also fine.

There are [pattern types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/107606) as an experimental work in this area that might produce something somewhere in the future, but it's still in the planning stage.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could leave the boilerplate `_ => false` as is, but then it would allow to shortcut the `if` statement

```
fn compare(str_one: String, str_two: String, match_type: MatchType) -> bool {
    match match_type {
        MatchType::Exact | MatchType::Lower | MatchType::Greater => {
            let f_one = str_one.parse::<f64>();
            let f_two = str_two.parse::<f64>();

            match (f_one, f_two, match_type) {
                (Ok(f_one), Ok(f_two), MatchType::Exact)   => f_one == f_two,
                (Ok(f_one), Ok(f_two), MatchType::Greater) => f_one > f_two,
                (Ok(f_one), Ok(f_two), MatchType::Lower)   => f_one < f_two,
                _ => false
            }
        },
        MatchType::Other => false,
    }
}
```